# Dyanamically change the font color of Kendo Numeric textbox

Tags: kendo-ui, kendonumerictextbox

I am using Kendo Numeric text box to display decimal values.I want to change the font color based on the user input.How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Can do this in JQuery easily by changing the style on the change and spin event of the input:

On your numeric text box add the events:

```
 $("#numerictextbox").kendoNumericTextBox(
    {
        change: onChangeOrSpin,
        spin: onChangeOrSpin
   });
```

Then in the event handler call:

```
  function onChangeOrSpin() 
  {
       var val = this.value();
        changeFontColour(val);
  } 

  function changeFontColour(val)
    {
        if(val < 5)
        {
            $("#numerictextbox, .k-input").css('font-family','Arial');
            $("#numerictextbox, .k-input").css('font-style','italic');
            $("#numerictextbox, .k-input").css('font-weight','bold');
            $("#numerictextbox, .k-input").css('color','blue');
        }
        else
        {
              $("#numerictextbox, .k-input").css('font-family','Times New Roman');
            $("#numerictextbox, .k-input").css('font-style','normal');
           $("#numerictextbox, .k-input").css('font-weight','normal');
            $("#numerictextbox, .k-input").css('color','black');

        }
    }
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/loanburger/nwsw4yeq/

**Update:**

For multiple numeric inputs on the same page, use classes and add a different class to each input so you can distinguish between then when you need to change the colour. Then use a data attribute to find the correct one to change.

You cannot use the id because there are two parts to how kendo creates the widget:

1. The first part is the input for editing the value.  This is the
   one the user interacts with.  This input will be given the class:
   `numerictextbox numericOne k-input`
2. There is a second input of interest which is the one used to display the value after the widget looses focus this one gets the classes: `k-formatted-value numerictextbox numericOne k-input`

Neither of these inputs get an id and you don't want to use the native Kendo classes either so using a distinct class on each of your numeric widget controls, you can identify which colours to change since that class will get added to both inputs in the widget.

See here: https://jsfiddle.net/loanburger/4evy3tcg/